# sticky navbar with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my navbar sticky, but I don't know how to integrate javascript. could you help me
my code is like this

```
<header>
<div class="menuhd">
<div class="main_menu home_menu" >
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
<nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">


<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                     aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
                  </button>
                  
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu-item" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><i class="fas fa-house-user"></i> <a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-tshirt"></i><a href="spring.php">OUTFITS</a></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: You do not need javascript to make your nav sticky. Do you just want it to stick to the top of the page when the user scrolls?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: have you tried "position: sticky" property of CSS